# Mono application using Console.CancelKeyPress cannot be run in background

Tags: c#, linux, mono, console, sigint

I have a console application in Mono under Linux that uses Console.CancelKeyPress to listen for `SIGINT`. However, this applications refuses to run in the background, as it always immediately gets stopped.

Here's a reduced example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(Console_CancelKeyPress);
        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping");
        Thread.Sleep(100000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In handler.");
    }
}
```

If I try to run this application in the background under bash, this is the result:

```
~/test$ mono test.exe &
[1] 4516
~/test$

[1]+  Stopped                 mono test.exe
~/test$
```

I had to hit enter again to see the "stopped" message, but it happens immediately. As you can see, it never reaches the `Console.WriteLine` call.

If I try to send `SIGINT` using `kill` (which should end the process because the handler doesn't set `e.Cancel` to `true`), nothing happens until I resume the process using `fg`, at which point it ends immediately (it never enters the handler).

If I start the process in the foreground, then interrupt it with `ctrl-z` and use `bg`, it again gets stopped immediately, only this time if I send `SIGINT` and then resume it with `fg`, the handler does get invoked.

If I remove the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event handler assignment, the process runs in the background just fine.

I'm using Mono 2.10.8 and Debian 6.0.2.

If all else fails, I can replicate the functionality I need using `Mono.Unix.UnixSignal`, but if someone has a solution for this I'd definitely like to hear it.

**UPDATE:** It seems there's another problem with `Console.CancelKeyPress` for my purposes. I will run my process using `nohup` so the input is not a console but /dev/null. In this situation, Mono will never trigger the `CancelKeyPress` event, even if you send SIGINT using `kill`. `UnixSignal` it is, then.

Comment: ooh, that is very strange. I see the same on my 2.10.8 install here (ubuntu)

Comment: look like a bug, huh?